# Paginating XHTML to PNG image files using Flying Saucer

Tags: html, image, flying-saucer

I'm using Flying Saucer to create PNG image files from XHTML.  I then use another facility to collect these into a PDF, along with a bunch of other text n images.

While I could convert our PDF export processing to iText, that would be a rather large undertaking....

The problem I have is that some XHTML content I have need to be paginated when exported to PNG image files.  I'm OK with just a simple 'clip-style' break between the image files.

Here's what I'm using just to render the entire content to a single file and it works well.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("AAA", "." + suffix);
XHTMLPanel panel = new XHTMLPanel();
panel.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

InputStream is = <create content>;

panel.setDocument(is, "");

Graphics2DRenderer renderer = new Graphics2DRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(panel.getDocument(),"");

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(DEFAULT_WIDTH,
         DEFAULT_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
graphics.setColor(Color.white);
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

renderer.layout(graphics,null);         
renderer.render(graphics);

ImageIO.write(img, suffix, file);
```

However, some of my content 'spans' a couple of pages and the processing above just displays the top DEFAULT_HEIGHT pixels and clips the remainder.

Is there a way to 'iterate' through the panel content (vertically) and render, say X pixels of content to unique image files?  That's sort of what ITextRenderer does, but how can I render the individual pages to separate image files?

Answer (score -1):

Figgered this out.  Fortunately the Graphics2DRenderer lets me know how large an XHTML section is (width n height).

I just re-render into a BufferedImage of that size, and then iteratively peel off parts of that full image into 'page' images with the Grahpics2D.drawImage(Image, , ) and then dump those to disk.

Not the prettiest, but it works.